# How does shell(bash) works in linux i.e How it handles background running process

Tags: c, linux

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
void my_isr();
int main()
{
    signal(SIGALRM,my_isr);
    alarm(5);
    pause();
    printf("in main()...\n");//case2 comments it //case 1 & 3 uncomments it
    return 0;//case 1 & 2 comments this line // case 3 uncomment it
}
void my_isr()
{
    printf("I am in my_isr()\n");
}
```

If I am running process in background

**Case 1** : If I didn't `return 0` in main function at end of main scope, it( shell-bash) prints `exit` value 13(no of printable characters in last printf). Why only last printf ? Is it undefined behaviour ?

```
xyz@xyz-PC:~/s_flow$ ./a.out &
[1] 9158
xyz@xyz-PC:~/s_flow$ I am in my_isr()
in main()...

[1]+  Exit 13                 ./a.out
```

Then shell prints `Exit` with status value `13`.

**Case 2** : If there is no `return 0` at the end of main() and I removed `last printf`(which prints 13 characters)

```
xyz@xyz-PC:~/s_flow$ ./a.out &
[1] 9169
xyz@xyz-PC:~/s_flow$ I am in my_isr()

[1]+  Exit 255                ./a.out
```

Then shell prints Exit with status value as 255. How ?

**case 3** : Finally If everything is provided correctly i.e If I mention `return 0` at end of main() then shell print's `Done` message with no value.

```
xyz@xyz-PC:~/s_flow$ ./a.out &
[1] 9178
xyz@xyz-PC:~/s_flow$ I am in my_isr()
in main()...

[1]+  Done                    ./a.out
```

I understood roughly why bash `shell` prints `Exit 13`, `Exit 255` & `Done` but any further explanation is welcome. my real question is how shell is interacting with OS when one process is running in background, where I can find these shell messages ? and how `OS` returns these status value to `shell` & then shell prints ? Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you compiled with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`)  you'll get useful warnings and you could debug your program in the `gdb` debugger. Also, read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) & [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html); calling `printf` inside the signal handler is forbidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 13 is the result code of your program. It terminates with result code 13 in both cases - when it is run background and foreground as well. But when the program is running foreground then bash does not print the result code. But you can check that the result code is actually 13 for foreground run:

```
$ ./a.out
in isr() 16664:..
in isr() 16664:..
in main()...
$ echo $?
13
```

And why it is 13? Result code is normally the result code of the `main()` function. But the `main()` function does not contain any return statement so the result is architecture dependent. In this case the value 13 is the return value from the last `printf` call because

```
printf("in main()...\n");
```

returns 13 what is the length of the printed string. And the value 13 remains in the register by chance.

Comment: wow great bro !! i thought i am missing something .. u spotted on thanks

Answer (score 2):

The "random" exit code is due to the incorrect return type of `main()`. `main()` should return `int`, which is the value returned to the calling environment.

When a background process completes, then the its associated terminal is notified of the completion with its exit status. But your program doesn't send its exit status correctly. This is technically [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: i putted int main(), still it is showing ..ok  if i am putting exit(0) in my_isr then after pause whatever statement are there are not executing .. how to print last printf statement

Comment: You can't `exit()` from a signal handler. Same with `printf()`. You can't call functions that are not signal-safe. See the [async signal safe functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) for the list of functions that are safe. Before C99, `main()` is required to return an int explicitly. Since C99, zero is implicitly returned and doesn't require you to call `exit()` or `return` a value explicitly. So you may need to `return` or `exit()` if you are using C89/C90.